# Create new columns in a dataframe with values from existing column

Tags: r

Attached is a sample data that I have for which I am trying to create additional columns

```
Part A    B   C   D 
abc  100  30  40  50
def  0    23  24  25
ghi  21   23  45   50
```

I need to create 16 columns namely a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2 ..... d3, d4, The value of a1 would be A/4, a2=A/4 ... d1=D/4 and so on.

I tried using the for loop condition

```
for (i in 1:4) {
    data$a[i] <- A/4
    data$b[I] <- B/4       
}
```

The final data should look like
Column names with respective values in below format

```
 Part a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3 b4...d4
```

Comment: So the values on a1 are same as a2, a3, a4, as they are all divided by 4, why?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"Part A    B   C   D 
abc  100  30  40  50
def  0    23  24  25
ghi  21   23  45   50")

x4 <- t(apply(D[-1], 1, rep, each=4)/4)
rownames(x4) <- x$Part
colnames(x4) <- paste0(rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each=4), 1:4)
x4
```

If you want a dataframe you can do:

```
x4.df <- cbind(data.frame(Part=x$Part), x4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loops:

```
df <- data.frame(Part = c("abc","def","ghi"), 
                 A = c(100,0,21), 
                 B = c(30,23,23), 
                 C = c(40,24,45), 
                 D = c(50,25,50)) 

final_df <- df # Start with copy of original
for (i in 1:4) {
  new_df <- (df[,-1])/4 # create data frame with div 4 values
  names(new_df) <- paste0(names(df)[-1],i) # create col names
  final_df <- data.frame(final_df, new_df)
}


##  Part   A  B  C  D    A1   B1    C1    D1    A2   B2    C2    D2    A3
##1  abc 100 30 40 50 25.00 7.50 10.00 12.50 25.00 7.50 10.00 12.50 25.00
##2  def   0 23 24 25  0.00 5.75  6.00  6.25  0.00 5.75  6.00  6.25  0.00
##3  ghi  21 23 45 50  5.25 5.75 11.25 12.50  5.25 5.75 11.25 12.50  5.25
##    B3    C3    D3    A4   B4    C4    D4
##1 7.50 10.00 12.50 25.00 7.50 10.00 12.50
##2 5.75  6.00  6.25  0.00 5.75  6.00  6.25
##3 5.75 11.25 12.50  5.25 5.75 11.25 12.50
```

Comment: bnair - would you officially accept one of the answers or upvote a proposed solution? thnx